# Difference between Read N words and Number of words: M in fasttext

Tags: fasttext

```
./fastText-0.1.0/fasttext skipgram -input wiki_data/enwik9 -output wiki_data/result/enwik9
Read 142M words
Number of words:  847816
Number of labels: 0
Progress: 100.0%  words/sec/thread: 62604  lr: 0.000000  loss: 0.607538  eta: 0h0m
```

What the *Number of words: M* signifies?
And why is it different from *Read N words*?

Answer (score 3):

N in "Read N words" is the total number of words in all your dataset that are separated with white spaces.

M in "number of words M" is the number of unique words in all you dataset and constitutes your vocabulary. However, this number might, in reality, be smaller than the number of unique words in the dataset if the option "minCount" which is the minimal number of word occurrences was set to a number greater than 1.

To illustrate this, here is an example.
Assume that you have a data set with :

```
__label__0 this sentence is an example
__label__1 here is another example
```

If you run fasttext with mincount = 1:

- The number of read words will be 9 (N) : [this, sentence, is, an example, here, is, another, example]
- The number of unique words greater than mincount will be 7 (M) : [this, sentence, is, an example, here, another]

If you run fasttext with mincount = 2:

- The number of read words will be 9 (N) : [this, sentence, is, an example, here, is, another, example]
- The number of unique words greater than mincount will be 2 (M) : [is, example]